# How do I map coordinates from one array of arrays to another, keeping the same order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that look like:

```
[["Jenny", 4],["Jayden", 8]]
// and 
[[23.6778,-67.87],[87.8652,-9.97]].
```

The coordinates are in exactly the same position as I'd like them to be in the new array.
I want it to ultimately end up like:

```
[["Jenny", 4, 23.6778,-67.87], ["Jayden", 8, 87.8652,-9.97]
```

Is there a way to map the coordinates to the arrays in the first array? I've tried a few things, but no luck.

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map function and spread operator for joining arrays:

```
let a = [["Jenny", 4],["Jayden", 8]]
let b = [[23.6778,-67.87],[87.8652,-9.97]]
let c = a.map((item, idx) => [...item, ...b[idx]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Denis. I hadn't used the "..." operator before, so this is good to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop and then push it destructured (`...`).

```js
const arr1 = [
  ["Jenny", 4],
  ["Jayden", 8],
];

const arr2 = [
  [23.6778, -67.87],
  [87.8652, -9.97],
];

const arr3 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) arr3.push([...arr1[i], ...arr2[i]]);

console.log(arr3);
```

---

**Some Useful resources:**

- [Destructuring assignment Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Array.push() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Thanks very much; I'd never used that operator before. The code works now!

Comment: @olliemel It is fairly new, was released in `ES2015`.

Comment: Why doesn't the output look like the OP's?

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm sure it won't be the last time I use it now. Thanks for the resources too

Comment: @showdev, I just needed to add extra array brackets in, so `arr3.push([...arr1[i], ...arr2[i]]);`

Comment: @showdev I missed  `[]`, Thank you, I added.